# Cannot convert value of type '(AccountViewController) -> () -> (AccountViewController)'

Tags: swift, oop, delegates

Fairly new to Swift so please be easy on me. Working with an inherited codebase.

Getting this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(AccountViewController) -> () -> (AccountViewController)' to expected argument type 'GetUserDelegate?'
```

This code is in my view controller. This is the only code out of this example that I wrote:

fileprivate var userDataSource = getAPI().getUser(delegate: self)

This code is part of my API definition:

```
func getUser(delegate: GetUserDelegate?) {
    sessionManager.request(ApiRequests.user).validate().responseJSON { (response: Alamofire.DataResponse<Any>) -> Void in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            guard let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSONObject: value) else {
                delegate?.apiError(code: nil, message: "Cannot decode user")
                return
            }

            delegate?.getUserSuccess(user: user)
        case .failure(let err):
            delegate?.apiError(code: nil, message: err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the protocol:

```
protocol GetUserDelegate: APIErrorDelegate {
    func getUserSuccess(user: User)
}
```

Now elsewhere in the code I'm seeing similar functions where all they pass in is delegate: self, but this doesn't appear to work and gives me the above error.

My guess is that this is because I am setting this in the class definition directly, rather than in one of the class methods - am I on the right track here? I've done a decent chunk of OOP coding before, but I've never used a delegate design pattern, so I'm not totally understanding implementation here I think.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is clear, you should implement such `GetUserDelegate` inside of your `AccountViewController`, something like:

```
class AccountViewController: UIViewController, GetUserDelegate {
   func getUserSuccess(user: User) {
     // stuff here //
   }
}
```

Comment: Would using an extension also work for this? I'm seeing something similar in extensions in other view controllers. If so I think I may more or less understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've got it. I'm just verifying before I select this as the answer.